# Are Array object with keys bad? (mixed associative array style)

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

In a recent project I needed ordered entries plus a special type property for the collection and this is what I ended up with:

```
var array=['a','b'];
array.type = 'alphabet';

console.log(array);
//["a", "b", type: "alphabet"]
```

so far it's working fine ,

I didn't find much documentation on this kind of array, are there any cons in this kind of design?

Comment: You *can* do that, but you're not actually using the array as array then, so consumers of this array will need to know that your "array" is special in some way and what to do with it, which is reason enough not to do it.

Comment: @deceze this is a simplified example the actual code I'm working is `points = [ [type:'M', [0,0]] , [type:'C', [22,33],[34,42],[66,88] ]  ..... ]` and I need to keep order of wrapping array

Comment: @maioman: That'll throw an syntax error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Comment: @Alnitak Oh okay. Sorry.

Comment: That particular syntax doesn't work to begin with. Why do you need a `type` key *and* an order? Is the first entry always the type and the rest of the values follow? Then there's no need for the `type` key. There *is* a sane way to express this data structure using standard maps and lists without mixing these two concepts.

Comment: @deceze I assure you it's working || this array describes an svg path dValue that's why I need order

Comment: @maioman It can't be working, not using the specific syntax you've quoted above.

Comment: What he said. ^ I'm sure the SVG spec can express that data structure in a common format that a) doesn't violate Javascript's syntax and b) is universally valid.

Comment: Yes indeed that's misleading, and I still stand by my suggestion to use a different structure for the data, one which doesn't mix keys and un-keyed values.

Comment: @deceze my comment is misleading , I intended `console.log(points) //[ [type:'M', [0,0]] , [type:'C', [22,33],[34,42],[66,88] ] ..... ]` . I give for granted that as an array literal it will throw an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens to work within the confines of Javascript, but consider that this ***data structure*** may traverse systems and serialisation schemes and the same thing does not work everywhere else. You should keep your data structures "neutral" in a form that is understood across multiple systems; use the *array* and *object* data structures as intended. *Lists* and *maps* are universally understood concepts by now and supported everywhere; a mix of these two isn't necessarily and will potentially make it hard to transition your data to other systems. Even if you just need to *serialise* the data within Javascript (e.g. to store in a cookie), you'll run into problems.

You should simply express your data in an equally valid and universally understood format:

```
{ type: 'alphabet', values: ['a', 'b'] }
```

Comment: ___If___ there has to be some sort of serialization, you're right. In other words, whether or not to use a data structure like that depends on the use case.

Comment: Right, but the point is that in reality you cannot always predict where you're going to use this. Your app may grow and expand and suddenly the need to serialise pops up, but now you've already painted yourself into a corner. If you write to the documented API spec and use data structures as intended, the corners you can paint yourself into are much fewer.

Comment: Not every project has to be expand-able, though. I'm not disagreeing with you. I'm just saying this structure is perfectly valid _in certain cases_.

Comment: you're absolutely right about serialization (an aspect I hadn't thought about).

Comment: instead as performance is concerned I tested the hybrid-array vs the object with nested array; the interesting part is the deviating browser based results (on chrome the hydrid-array is 10% more performant while 30% slower on FF ; and to my surprise FF is much more performant overall). [If you want take a look](http://jsperf.com/array-with-keyprop-vs-object)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this works. I don't really see why you wouldn't use it, if it meets your needs.
However, there are a few things to keep in mind:

`JSON.stringify` will not stringify these properties, and `for` loops iterating over the array will only catch these properties when using `for...in`:

```js
var array = ['a','b'];
array.type = 'alphabet';

document.write('JSON.stringify(array)<br/>');
document.write(JSON.stringify(array));

document.write('<br/><br/>for in:<br/>');
for(var a in array)
    document.write(a + ': ' + array[a] + '<br/>'); // Will show `type`

document.write('<br/>"normal" for loop:<br/>')
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    document.write(i + ': ' + array[i] + '<br/>'); // Will not show `type`
```

This means that, as [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) mentioned, if you need to serialize your data, you're going to run into problems.
However, if that is not the case, then this data structure works just fine.

Comment: The behaviour of `JSON.stringify` is a good point, but otherwise, yeah, this doesn't seem any worse than e.g. adding custom properties to a DOM element.